# Compare the values of 2 input fields to validate the form in Angular 7 through the template

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-validation

I'm in my first weeks of moving to Angular 7, I've been doing basic forms in my project using template based basic validations, but I need to validate the form now based on that the value of one field must be higher than the other

I've tried using the values themselves in the component controller, but while I'm able to confirm that the values are valid or not, I'm unable to show the user what the problem is, using this code

```
if (issueThresholdForm.value.lowScore > issueThresholdForm.value.highScore) {
  // Show user error
  // This is the messing part, I guess
}
```

Here's the template that I'm using

```
<div *ngIf="_issueCategory">
  <form (submit)="submitIssueThreshold(issueThresholdForm)" #issueThresholdForm="ngForm">
    <mat-form-field class="half-width" floatLabel="always">
      <mat-label [translate]="'issueThreshold.modals.highScore'"></mat-label>
      <input name="highScore" type="number" matInput placeholder="0" [(ngModel)]="_issueCategory.highScore"
        required #highScore="ngModel">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field class="half-width" floatLabel="always">
      <mat-label [translate]="'issueThreshold.modals.lowScore'"></mat-label>
      <input name="lowScore" type="number" matInput placeholder="0" [(ngModel)]="_issueCategory.lowScore"
        required #lowScore="ngModel">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field class="full-width" floatLabel="always">
      <mat-label [translate]="'issueThreshold.modals.description'"></mat-label>
      <textarea name="description" matInput [(ngModel)]="_issueCategory.thresholdDescription">
            </textarea>
    </mat-form-field>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" [translate]="'modal-confirm.cancel'"></button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary primary" [disabled]="issueThresholdForm.invalid || issueThresholdForm.pristine" [translate]="'modal-confirm.submit'"></button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: add stackBlitz URL it will easy to get a fast answer

Comment: not related, but I would suggest to move to reactive forms, easy to handle such cases with custom validator. Sure you can do a custom validator in template driven forms too.

Comment: reactive forms would also help in writing better unit tests

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Edited with the same solution the reactive way. So create form group and add a custom validator attached to the form group:

```ts
_issueCategory = { lowScore: 1, highScore: 2 };

issueThresholdForm: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.issueThresholdForm = this.fb.group({
    highScore: [this._issueCategory.highScore, [Validators.required]],
    lowScore: [this._issueCategory.lowScore, [Validators.required]]
  }, { validators: validateScore })
}
```

Validator function:

```ts
export function validateScore(
  control: AbstractControl
): ValidationErrors | null {
  if (control && control.get("highScore") && control.get("lowScore")) {
    const highscore = control.get("highScore").value;
    const lowscore = control.get("lowScore").value;  
    return (lowscore > highscore) ? { scoreError: true } : null
  }
  return null;
}
```

Then you can remove ngModel (important!) since they should not be mixed with reactive forms. Also you can remove all validation like `required` for the form, so in the end an input can look simply like:

```ts
<input type="number" matInput placeholder="0" formControlName="lowScore">
```

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qk24ed-k3fh3e?file=app%2Finput-overview-example.ts)**

---

**ORIGINAL:**

I **strongly, strongly** suggest **[Reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)**, they might feel confusing at first, but totally worth it. You have better control over the form, and as mentioned in comment by Nithin Kumar Biliya, unit testing is easier.

That being said....

Here is a solution using template driven form, since that is what you currently are using.

You could make a directive that you attach to the form tag, and inside that directive have a validator to compare the values of highscore and lowscore and attach an error to the form, or return `null` (which is considered valid in forms). So the validator would look like this:

```ts
import { Directive } from "@angular/core";
import {
  AbstractControl,
  NG_VALIDATORS,
  Validator,
  ValidationErrors
} from "@angular/forms";

@Directive({
  selector: "[scoreValidation]",
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: ScoreValidatorDirective,
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class ScoreValidatorDirective implements Validator {
  constructor() {}

  // here control is the formgroup
  validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    if (control && control.get("highScore") && control.get("lowScore")) {

      // the form controls and their value
      const highscore = control.get("highScore").value;
      const lowscore = control.get("lowScore").value;

      // not valid, return an error
      if (lowscore > highscore) {
        return { scoreError: true };
      }
      // valid
      return null;
    }
    // form controls do not exist yet, return null
    return null;
  }
}
```

Add the directive to the declarations array in your appmodule, and use it by just attaching this directive to the form tag:

```ts
<form .... scoreValidation>
```

and error can be shown using `*ngIf="issueThresholdForm.hasError('scoreError')`

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qk24ed-5ur4dq?file=app/input-overview-example.html)**

Comment: I agree, I've read about the reactive forms and seems to do what we need to accomplish, but I wouldn't want to create a whole new component as a validator for this , I guess this would get quite complicated as the number of validators increase

Comment: sure, I understand, the same approach for reactive forms is much easier, that is, you just need to add a custom validator as a function, no need to create a directive. I can update my answer with an option for the same as reactive approach.

Comment: @user1712638, there, I added the reactive approach in my answer. Hopefully helps and is what you wish to do :)

Answer (score 2):

I strongly, recommand Reactive forms, but if you want to do that you can :

put the following `p tag` under the lowScore input:

```
<p class="text-danger" [hidden]="(lowerScore.value > higerScore.value ? false: true) || (lowScore.pristine && !issueThresholdForm.submitted)">
                    The lower scrore can not be greater than higer score
</p>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this wouldn't prevent the form from being submitted or the whole form or labeling the inputs with the issue, I think I'd go with the reactive forms

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`Custom Validations`**](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators) in [**`Reactive Forms`**](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) as follows.

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <form [formGroup]="myForm">

    <label>Low Score: </label>
    <input formControlName="lowScore" type="number">
    <br/><br/>
    <label>High Score: </label>
    <input formControlName="highScore" type="number">

    <div>
      <span style="color: red" *ngIf="myForm.get('highScore').touched && myForm.get('highScore').hasError('higherThan')">High score should be higher than lower score.</span>
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
export class AppComponent  {
  myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor() {

    this.myForm = new FormGroup({
      highScore: new FormControl(0, [this.lowerThan('lowScore')]),
      lowScore: new FormControl(0, null)
    });
  }
  lowerThan(field_name): ValidatorFn {

    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {

      const input = control.value;

      const isLower = control.root.value[field_name] >= input;

      return isLower ? {'lowerThan': {isLower}}: null;
    };
  }
}
```

**Find Working [StackBlitz Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-58155812?file=src/app/app.component.ts).**

Comment: This only get fired only on launching the form, not upon submitting it, which isn't very useful :D, am I missing something ?